# Reporting on server and client

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, wcf, crystal-reports

I'm looking for a reporting solution that works on the server and in the front-end. The problem is that the front-end technology has yet to be decided from ASP.NET web forms, ASP.NET MVC or Silverlight.

So I'd like to use the same reporting framework for generating reports on the server (business layer abstracted through WCF) to PDF format and also present reports in a viewer through ASP.NET or Silverlight, where users can preview the report, adapt filtering and eventually export to PDF or Excel/CSV.

My client also likes to have a report designer.

Would I be able to do all that with Crystal Reports? Also, would I be able somehow to use the same report definition on the front-end and back-end? Other framework suggestions are also welcome, although we don't want the SQL reporting services approach here because it requires a seperate reporting service application in IIS.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I work for Telerik. Telerik Reporting allows you to create .NET native reports using its Visual Studio based report designer. These reports can be viewed an any of the included report viewers, ASP.NET, Silverlight, WPF, and WinForms. If you decide to go with MVC, its also possible to use that as well, see here (http://www.telerik.com/community/code-library/reporting/general/using-telerik-web-reportviewer-in-asp-net-mvc-application.aspx). Exporting to PDF, and several other file formats, is also possible with Telerik Reporting.

If you are interested in trying it out, a free trial version is available for download on the Telerik website (http://www.telerik.com).

Comment: We eventually chose for the Crystal reports which comes with the Visual Studio install and appears to be free of charge for intranet applications. The report designer is basically the same as SQL reporting services which is probably easier for us and is supported with a larger community.

Thanks for your input

Comment: @Koen- Be careful with the Crystal tools that come with VS. AFAIK, they do not support platforms like Silverlight and they can be a real pain to customize when integrated in applications. As a long time .NET developer, I don't know many projects that ultimately use teh Crystal tools for embedded reporting. Most use MSRS or a 3rd Party tool.

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a look at Teleriks offering (http://www.telerik.com/products/reporting.aspx) as it provides solutions for Silverlight, WPF and ASP.NET (not sure about ASP.NET MVC).

Answer (score 0):

Though not originally .NET I'll throw [i-net Clear Reports](http://www.inetsoftware.de/products/clear-reports) into the ring. It has a .NET server side port which can easily be integrated into your backend via it's extensive .NET API (or you can use it as standalone server as well). It generated PDFs and all other sorts of report documents.

On the front-end side there are some options: embed HTML, Images, PDF or use the Report Viewer 
 (which is not yet Silverlight but Java) - anyways: it's quite flexible.

Another up-side: There is a free and easy to use report designer tool as well. You can even edit reports directly from your report server and push them back in a new version.

Yep. I'm working for the company who made this. (give it a try)